# ibrokers R - Financial Advisor - order placement

Tags: r, ibrokers

I'm trying to place an OCO order on a Financial advisor account using ibrokers and R.

How do I place an OCO order?  How could I include a stop and take profit with each leg of the OCO that's also cancelled?

Thanks for any guidance!

Sample code:

```
Crude <- twsFuture('CL', 'NYMEX', '201505') 
fiveMin <- strftime(Sys.Date(), "%Y%m%d") 
fiveMin <- paste(fiveMin, "09:05:00", sep=" ")

Price <- reqHistoricalData(tws, Contract=Crude, barSize = "5 mins", 
                           duration = "30 S", useRTH = 0,endDateTime=(fiveMin))

HighPriceStr <- toString(Price$CLK5.High)
MktHigh <- (as.numeric(HighPriceStr))

LowPriceStr <- toString(Price$CLK5.Low)
MktLow <- (as.numeric(LowPriceStr))

#calculate range width
range <- (MktHigh - MktLow)

#enter orders if 5 min range <= .50 cents
if (range <= .50){
#place oco lmt entry @ mkt high + .02, lmt sell @ mkt low - .02 

#sample limit order for FA account group named Futures.
#IBrokers:::.placeOrder(twsOC, Crude, twsOrder(reqIds(tws), "SELL", "8", "LMT", lmtPrice = (Stop), faGroup ="Futures", faMethod ="EqualQuantity"))
}
```

Comment: You might search or ask on http://quant.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get a response here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

Interactive Brokers uses OCA orders, one cancels all.

Here's a sample:

```
IBrokers:::.placeOrder(twsOC, MiniCrude, twsOrder(reqIds(tws), "BUY", "3", "LMT", lmtPrice = (BreakTarget), ocaGroup = (breakerdirection), faGroup ="MiniFutures", faMethod ="EqualQuantity")) 
IBrokers:::.placeOrder(twsOC, MiniCrude, twsOrder(reqIds(tws), "BUY", "3", "STP", auxPrice = (BreakStop), ocaGroup = (breakerdirection), faGroup ="MiniFutures", faMethod ="EqualQuantity"))
```

The second part of the question, how to place the above orders only after the limit entry has been filled.

reqExecutions()

I don't have the sample code written yet.